# Request does not match any route in Magento 2 API

Tags: php, api, magento, magento2

Need to help in Magento 2 API.

Every time when I call Login API show below response.

```
{“message”:“Request does not match any route.“,”trace”:null}
```

My Login xml file as per below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V6/customer/registration" method="POST">
        <service class="ApiV6\CustomerApi\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="registrationAccount"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V6/customer/login" method="POST">
        <service class="ApiV6\CustomerApi\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="login"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>

API URL: /V6/customer/login
Username: test@gmail.com
Password: ******
```

Comment: could you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet but alternative we have update new version copy from old working version then working fine.